# How to use 2 Interactive Views together in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a project where I have to swipe intractable view from both the left and right side of the screen.

Using this I was able to add a view which I could swipe from the left

```
<Interactable.View
  horizontalOnly={true}
  snapPoints={[{x: -340}, {x: 0}]}
  dragEnabled={true}
  initialPosition={{x: -340 , y: 0}}
  boundaries={{left: -340, right: 0}}>

  <View >**My Screen**</View>

</Interactable.View>
```

And underneath this code I wrote the Interactabel view to be swiped from right

```
  <Interactable.View
    horizontalOnly={true}
    snapPoints={[{x: 0}, {x: 340}]}
    dragEnabled={true}
    initialPosition={{x: 340 , y:0 }}
    boundaries={{left: 0, right: 340}}>

      <View >**My Screen**</View>

  </Interactable.View>
```

But when I run the code only the first interactable view is showing.And If I comment the first one and run the code the second interactable view is seen.I need to view both views together.

I hope my question is clear.Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.